# How can I reset my windows server password

Tags: google-compute-engine

How can I reset my windows server password. I'm using google cloud compute engine and am trying to reset the password to login to my server. I've tried to do it using Google SDK Shell but I seem to not be doing something correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command to modify the Windows admin password: gcloud compute instances add-metadata [instance-name] --metadata gce-initial-windows-password=[password] --project [project-id] --zone [zone-name]

Keep in mind that in order for this to work the new password has to meet the Windows [password requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994562%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). If the password you enter doesn't meet the requirements, the metadata will be updated but the password won't update inside the Windows VM.